# Fundamental group of Klein Bottle with 2 points removed.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does anyone know what this group is.  Just want to know what the group is.  Thanks.

Comment: think of the case, when Klein bottle has one point removed. You can enlarge the hole all along to get a regular strip loop and a Mobius strip loop glued at one point.

Answer (score 1):

It is a free group generated by $3$ letters. If you prefer a proof. See here for one point off case.

[fundamental group of the Klein bottle minus a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287101/fundamental-group-of-the-klein-bottle-minus-a-point)

And if you continue to minus points, you will see, whenever you removed a point, you generated a new circle attached to it.

Comment: I calculated the fundamental group of the torus with two points removed.  I know the group is $F_3$. However, the second calculation I got the group. $ <a, b, c, d|aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}>$  Is this equal to $F_3?$  And if so why?

Comment: are you sure the fundamental group is $\langle a,b,c,d | aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}\rangle$? I cannot see it is a free group either.